# UDP in c: Extra characters getting added to file when saving received data in chunks

Tags: c, file, file-io, udp, printf

I'm trying to get a simple send and receive UDP program working, but I'm having a bit of trouble with saving the received data. As far as I can tell the data is being sent and received properly, as I've printed it out on both ends. Before I write the data to the file (if I just print out the received chunk) it doesn't have any extra characters, so I'm a bit lost as to where they are coming from.

When I append each chunk of received data to the file it adds a "^P^B^GÐ^?" after every chunk written. for example one of the chunks ended with "We, therefore^P^B^GÐ^?," instead of "We, therefore,".

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

I've seemed to have gotten things working semi-better, I'm now having an issue with it replacing the first character of every chunk with a null character, for example:

"^@N CONGRESS, July 4, 1776." instead of "IN CONGRESS, July 4, 1776."

It's doing this for the first char of every chunk received, I've tried multiple debug print statements but can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Here is my Receive and Send functions:

```
void receiveFile() {
int addr_len, bytesRead;
char recvData[BUFSIZE]; // Buffer to store received data
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

// Set up struct to receive data from our port and address
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero), 8);

addr_len = sizeof (struct sockaddr);

printf("\nWaiting for data on port %d\n", port);


//Keep reading data from the socket
while (1) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("dummyfile.txt", "ab");

    memset(recvData, 0, BUFSIZE);
    bytesRead = recvfrom(sock, recvData, BUFSIZE, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &addr_len);
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < bytesRead; x++) {
        fputc(recvData[x], fp);
    }

    // Print out who we're receiving from and what we're recieving
    printf("Receiving data from %s : %d\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),
            ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

    fclose(fp);
}}
```

Here is the Send Function:

```
void sendFile() {
// Announce who we're sending data to
if(DEBUG) { printf("\nSending %s to %s:%d\n", filename, address, port); }

// Open file
FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (file == NULL) {
  perror("Invalid File\n");
  exit(1);
}

// Get size of the file
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
int filesize = ftell(file);
rewind(file);

int curPos = 0;
int dataSize = 0;

while(curPos < filesize) {

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr; 
    struct hostent *recvr;

    char sendData[BUFSIZE]; // stores message to be sent
    memset(sendData, 0, BUFSIZE);

    int byte, i;
    for(i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++){
        if((filesize - curPos) > 0) {
            byte = fgetc(file);
            sendData[i] = byte;
            curPos++;
            dataSize++;
        }
        else { break; }
    }

    recvr = gethostbyname(address);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *) recvr->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero), 8);

    if(DEBUG) {
        char tempData[1201];
        strncpy(tempData, sendData, 1200);
        tempData[1201] ='\0';
        printf("%s\n\n\n\n\n", tempData);
    }

    sendto(sock, sendData, dataSize, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
    dataSize = 0;
}

fclose(file);}
```

Comment: Did you forget the filename, address, port parameters to the sending function?  Or are they really global variables?  The send loop does not check for EOF before copying the character to the buffer.  If the file is shorter than BUFSIZE bytes, then you end up with a lot of characters, usually ÿ (y-umlaut, or LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, aka 0xFF) at the end of the buffer.  It is not clear why you need 3 counters - i, curPos, and dataSize - storing the same value.

Comment: OK - ignore the comment about 3 counters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you change the printing to:

```
fprintf(fp, "%.*s", bytesRead, recvData);
```

There is a guarantee that [`recvfrom()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvfrom.html) will not null terminate your messages; you would have to transmit the null terminator yourself.

---

I can't tell what your residual problem is.  I have the following to complete programs working back to back.  I've scrutinized the saved file for NULs with no problem.

I ran them as:

```
./recv & sleep 1; ./send; kill %1
```

#### recv.c

```
#include "posixver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> /* sockaddr_in */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* inet_ntoa() */
#include "stderr.h"

static void receiveFile(int sock, int port, char *filename)
{
    //Keep reading data from the socket
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "ab");
    if (fp == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to open file %s", filename);

    printf("\nWaiting for data on port %d\n", port);
    while (1)
    {
        char recvData[BUFSIZ]; // Buffer to store received data
        struct sockaddr_storage addr;
        struct sockaddr_in *client_addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;
        memset(recvData, 0, sizeof(recvData));
        socklen_t addr_len = sizeof (struct sockaddr_storage);
        int bytesRead = recvfrom(sock, recvData, sizeof(recvData), 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &addr_len);
        if (bytesRead < 0)
            err_syserr("Failed to read from socket");
        err_remark("Read %d bytes\n", bytesRead);
        for (int x = 0; x < bytesRead; x++)
        {
            fputc(recvData[x], fp);
        }
        fflush(fp);

        // Print out who we're receiving from and what we're receiving
        //char *rem_host = inet_ntoa(client_addr->sin_addr);
        //int   rem_port = ntohs(client_addr->sin_port);
        //printf("Receiving %d bytes from %s:%d\n", bytesRead, rem_host ? rem_host : "<unknown>", rem_port);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    struct sockaddr_in *server_addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    server_addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr->sin_port = htons(5190);

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc > 1)
        err_usage("");
    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to open DGRAM socket");
    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to bind DGRAM socket");
    receiveFile(fd, 5190, "dummy.text");

    return(0);
}
```

#### send.c

```
#include "posixver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "stderr.h"

#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void)0)

enum { DEBUG = 1 };

static void sendFile(int sock, const char *filename, char *address, int port)
{
    // Announce who we're sending data to
    if (DEBUG)
        printf("\nSending %s to %s:%d\n", filename, address, port);

    // Open file
    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to open file %s", filename);

    // Get size of the file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int filesize = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    int curPos = 0;
    int dataSize = 0;

    while (curPos < filesize)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr; 
        struct hostent *recvr;
        char sendData[BUFSIZ]; // stores message to be sent
        memset(sendData, 0, BUFSIZ);

        int byte, i;
        for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZ; i++){
            if ((filesize - curPos) > 0) {
                byte = fgetc(file);
                sendData[i] = byte;
                curPos++;
                dataSize++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        recvr = gethostbyname(address);
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *) recvr->h_addr_list[0]);
        bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero), 8);

        if(DEBUG) {
            char tempData[1201];
            strncpy(tempData, sendData, 1200);
            tempData[1201] ='\0';
            printf("SEND:\n%s\n\n\n", tempData);
        }

        if (sendto(sock, sendData, dataSize, 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) < 0)
            err_syserr("Failed to send %d bytes\n", dataSize);
        dataSize = 0;
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc > 1)
        err_usage("");
    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to open DGRAM socket");
    sendFile(fd, "/etc/passwd", "localhost", 5190);

    return(0);
}
```

#### posixver.h

```
#ifndef JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H
#define JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H

/*
** Include this file before including system headers.  By default, with
** C99 support from the compiler, it requests POSIX 2001 support.  With
** C89 support only, it requests POSIX 1997 support.  Override the
** default behaviour by setting either _XOPEN_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE.
*/

/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L */

#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600   /* SUS v3, POSIX 1003.1 2004 (POSIX 2001 + Corrigenda) */
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500   /* SUS v2, POSIX 1003.1 1997 */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
#endif /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE && !_POSIX_C_SOURCE */

#endif /* JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H */
```

#### stderr.c and stderr.h

Actually, not standard at all, except in my code.  The functions used have the declarations:

```
extern void err_setarg0(const char *argv0);
extern void err_error(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2) NORETURN();
extern void err_remark(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2);
extern void err_syserr(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2) NORETURN();
extern void err_usage(const char *usestr) NORETURN();
```

The first records the program name. The second reports an error message and exits; the third reports a message and returns; the fourth reports an error message and adds error information from 'errno' and 'strerror()' if there is any to use; the last reports on how to use the program - in this case, the programs accept no arguments.  The full source code (quite large) is available from the [IIUG Software](http://www.iiug.org/software) site as part of the SQLCMD package available there, and various other programs that I've also submitted there.

Comment: Jonathan, he's calling `memset()` to zero-fill the receive-buffer before calling `recv()`; therefore, the buffer will be NUL-terminated.

Comment: Not necessarily, @Steve: the called function won't write beyond the boundary of the buffer passed, but does not promise not to leave extra data after the data it says it returned.  I'm not certain that it is the problem - that's why my response is phrased as a question.  But I think it is worth ensuring that the receiver only processes the data it was told was available.

Comment: AnthonyJK, actually Jonathan's on to something. If you send a message of length BUFSIZE, then the receive buffer won't be NUL-terminated and you won't be able to NUL-terminate it at the receiving end unless you increase the size of the buffer by one.

Comment: Hmm a new problem seems to have come up, when running this on an actual server, it doesn't write to the file, it just creates an empty one. When running on my localhost it sends the file perfectly. I have set the permissions in the directory to 755 but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @AnthonyJK: since your code doesn't check that the file opened OK, you can't be sure what's going on.  Also, are you sure you know which directory is the current directory of the server?

Comment: I replaced fprintf with fputc and it seemed to have fix the writing issue, but it seems to have created a new issue I mentioned above in my update. Thank you for all your help btw.